# Wiping data on Android: Device Admin versus Profile Owner

Tags: android, mdm, device-admin, android-managed-profile, profile-owner

Android 5.0 introduces a new concept of Profile Owner.

In my understanding Profile Owner is an advanced version of Device Admin (exists in Android since 2.2).

Both Device Admin and Profile Owner can wipe data via `DevicePolicyManager.wipeData(0)`.

I would like to know if there is a difference in behaviour of such a call for Device Admin and Profile Owner. I guess for a pure Device Admin it should wipe entire device (factory reset), and for a Profile Owner it should only wipe data for the current profile (so the coexisting personal data is untouched). But this is not clear from the API. Does anyone have a real experience in this?

Obviously I don't want to study the behaviour on my personal device (too risky), just would like to know if anyone already tried it on some test device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , When a device admin app calls the API , it wipes the entire device and when the same api is called with in the profile , it wipes data for current profile