# Performing enterprise wipe on devices using Work Profile?

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I wish to perform Enterprise Wipe on devices with Work Profiles. Essentially, this would enable admins from my company to remove all corporate-related information from a device without disturbing the individual's personal data.

I am aware a topic exists on this already: [Wiping data on Android: Device Admin versus Profile Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342461/wiping-data-on-android-device-admin-versus-profile-owner)

However, the topic talks about factory wipe and I certainly don't wish to do that. Any hints on how to accomplish this task?

Performed research on android forums + documentation and could not find the solution.

Comment: This would be on topic at Ask Different if the MDM were Apple centric. I don’t think it’s on topic for Super User, but perhaps the android site allows management software and framework questions? This may need a large edit to make it programming specific for this to stay open here by referencing a specific API call or code base in Android.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're talking about. This is a code question regarding the android-management-api, why are you talking about Apple? I'm new to AMAPI (Android Management API) is so I'm inquiring if such a feature is supported because I could not find the proper call when I read the documentation and played around with the existing methods.  For reference: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`enterprises.devices.delete`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) on a work profile. It will wipe and remove the work profile without touching the personal data. Which seems to be what you're looking for.

It's actually the only wipe possible for a work profile, it's not possible for the admin to wipe the entire device when it's set up with a work profile.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I need. I assumed it would wipe the entire device based on the documentation.